# Calculate mean and median efficiently

Tags: python, performance, numpy, mean, median

What is the most efficient way to sequentially find the mean and median of rows in a Python list?

For example, my list:

```
input_list = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
```

I want to produce an output list that contains:

```
output_list_mean = [1,1.5,2.3,3.25,4,4.7]
output_list_median = [1,1.5,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

Where the mean is calculated as follows:

- 1 = mean(1)
- 1.5 = mean(1,2) (i.e. mean of first 2 values in input_list)
- 2.3 = mean(1,2,4) (i.e. mean of first 3 values in input_list)
- 3.25 = mean(1,2,4,6) (i.e. mean of first 4 values in input_list)
  etc.

And the median is calculated as follows:

- 1 = median(1)
- 1.5 = median(1,2) (i.e. median of first 2 values in input_list)
- 2.0 = median(1,2,4) (i.e. median of first 3 values in input_list)
- 3.0 = median(1,2,4,6) (i.e. median of first 4 values in input_list)
  etc.

I have tried to implement it with the following loop, but it seems very inefficient.

```
import numpy

input_list = [1,2,4,6,7,8]

for item in range(1,len(input_list)+1):
    print(numpy.mean(input_list[:item]))
    print(numpy.median(input_list[:item]))
```

Comment: "seems very inefficient" compared to what? Did you time it? I suspect `import numpy` dominates the runtime (and you don't need it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anything you do yourself, especially with the median, is either going to require a lot of work, or be very inefficient, but Pandas comes with built-in efficient implementations of the functions you are after, the expanding mean is O(n), the expanding median is O(n*log(n)) using a skip list:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

input_list = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8]

>>> pd.expanding_mean(np.array(input_list))
array([ 1.     ,  1.5    ,  2.33333,  3.25   ,  4.     ,  4.66667])

>>> pd.expanding_median(np.array(input_list))
array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ])
```

Comment: Hello! I was looking after a solution like this for the same problem. But unfortunately, I was struggling with this due to the time that has passed. I am not sure if this effectively makes difference, but I think that there were some changes in implementations in `pandas` module. Can you help me please telling if your answer matches what I found in [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.mean.html) link? I think it is for new versions of pandas. Is it similar to what happened to `reduce` that was moved to `itertools` module?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.islice` to slice your array and use `np.fromiter` with `np.mean` :

```
>>> arr=np.array([1,2,4,6,7,8])
>>> l=arr.size
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> [np.fromiter(islice(arr,0,i+1),float).mean(dtype=np.float32) for i in xrange(l)]
[1.0, 1.5, 2.3333333, 3.25, 4.0, 4.6666665]
```

As an alternative answer you if you want the average you can use  [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html) to get a cumulative sum of the your elements and divide with the main array using `np.true_divide` :

```
>>> np.true_divide(np.cumsum(arr),arr)
array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5])
```

Comment: Thanks @Kasra! Can I use np to find the sequential median too?

Comment: @hoof_hearted Welcome! sorry what you mean by *sequential median*?

Comment: As in, I need to find the median of the first value (1), first two values (1,2), the first three values (1,2,3) etc. The output would be the same in this example (i.e. output_list = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5]), but I'm calculating the median of all values, as opposed to the mean. I hope that's clear

Comment: @hoof_hearted yep, and it's exactly what my answer does!

Comment: True, but that's because the median and mean are the same for this example. If the input numbers were not sequential, the median would be different. I may need to post this separately

Comment: @Kasra Thanks - I'll edit the question to be a bit more clear. But the median has been the real problem for me

Comment: @hoof_hearted Checkout the edit! but have a look at jaime's answer if you can use pandas its a better solution!

Comment: That `cumsum` part was smart!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,4,6,7,8])
```

Use `numpy.meshgrid` (there are other formulations that work) and `numpy.triu` to create an array with the values you are interested in.

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(a,a)
# y = a.repeat(len(a)).reshape(len(a), len(a))
c = np.triu(y)

>>> y
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]])
>>> c
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]])
```

Define a function that returns the median of all non-zero values and apply it to your *interesting* array.

```
def foo(a):
    '''return the the median of the non-zero elements of a 1d array
    '''
    return np.median(a[a.nonzero()])
d = np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, c)

>>> d
array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  5. ])
>>>
```